# I had a question on my Functional Analysis exam

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

Find all functions $f:R→R$ which are infinitely many times continuous-differentiable on R, where for every x from $R$, there exists a natural number n, such that $f^{(n)}{(x)}=0$.

I tried using the $Contraction$ and the $Fixed$ $Point$ $Theorem$ with $Lagrange's$ $theorem$, but didn't get any satisfactory results. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial